# Determine distance and location of point to another point based on their lat/lng

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude

Given 2 points (point1 and point2) with their latitudes/longitudes,

How can I tell if point2 is above or below, and to the right or left of point1? How would I calculate the angle (alpha in the image) between the 2 points?

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Is "up" North in your example?

Comment: Since you're talking of lat/lon... are you on a sphere or on a flat surface?

Comment: For the angle between two points, see [`Math.Atan2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx)

Comment: @abe ..no, up is not north in my example ..the problem is: the 2 points are only determinated by their lat/lng ..no directions..

Comment: @romkyns: Flat surface (for now :))

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer, but it might point you in the right direction (ha ha, couldn't resist that).

You have to be quite careful when framing this sort of question for yourself.  First off, are you concerned with taking account of the (approximate) sphericity of the Earth, or are you a rough old b****r who will be satisfied with treating the surface of the Earth as a plane ?

If the former, direct your attention to [this web page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) which is probably the single most-linked-to explanation of how to calculate distance and azimuth on a sphere.  Note, as that page explains, that the azimuth (what you call the angle) of the line from point 1 to point 2 changes constantly along the line.  That line, as you will discover, is a segment of a great circle.  Only when the great circle connecting the two points happens to pass through both poles or, even less likely, is the Equator, will the bearing of the destination from your current position not change continuously.

Note too that it is very easy to construct cases where the intial bearing of point 2 from point 1 is north of east, and the final bearing of the great circle from point 1 to point 2 is south of east, so using the initial bearing as an indicator of the relative locations of the 2 points can be tricky.

If you are a flat-Earther, and it's a perfectly respectable choice for navigation over short distances (up to 60nm or 100km perhaps), then get out your primary school geometry book and treat lat and long as planar measures. If you are still having problems edit your question.

Comment: thanks for the extended comment ... i think i will end up "mis-" using  the lat/lng as planar measures...
i thought, since lat/lng are unique for every location, there would be a good solution answering my question..but your cases proved that this could be tricky..thanks anyway for ur answer..